# Display barcode of each product on the invoice or delivery note, woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to display the barcode of the product on the invoice or delivery note, I try to do it with this code but it does not show the barcode image:

```
<?php
    echo get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ywbc_barcode_image', true );
    ?>
```

I am using the YITH WooCommerce Barcodes and QR Codes plugin, which adds a barcode for each product, in the following image you can see the meta data that the plugin adds (Product Post Meta).
[image: Meta Datos Barcode Product]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `do_action` wherever you like the order barcode to appear, assuming you have access to either the `$order` object or order id, like this:

`do_action ( 'yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter', $order->get_id() );`

You can then use that to call an action that will display the barcode on all locations you've added the `do_action`:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter_call_back' ) ) {
    add_action( 'yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter', 'yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter_call_back', 10, 1 );
    function yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter_call_back( $id ) {
        ob_start();
        $css = ob_get_clean();
        YITH_YWBC()->show_barcode( $id, true, $css );
    }
}
```

This last part goes in the functions.php of your (child)theme or should be added with a plugin like Code Snippets.

If you need the product barcode you will have to use the product ID instead of the order ID, assuming you have access to the `$product` object.

`do_action ( 'yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter', $product->get_id() );`

Comment: Thanks for the help, your code works very well to display the barcode of the **Order**, but it is necessary to show the barcode of each **Product** on the invoice or delivery note template. Can you help me?

Comment: If I use this code it only shows me the barcode of each product but not the image `<?php
    echo get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ywbc_barcode_value', true );
    ?>`

Comment: THX. I could solve it with your code, I could show the barcode of the order and for products I did it, I just had to change: **$product** `<?php do_action ( 'yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter_product', $product->get_id() );
    ?>` `if ( ! function_exists( 'yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter_call_back_product' ) ) { add_action( 'yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter_product', 'yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter_call_back_product', 10, 1 );
    function yith_wc_barcodes_and_qr_filter_call_back_product( $product_id ) { ob_start(); $css = ob_get_clean(); YITH_YWBC()->show_barcode( $product_id, true, $css ); } }`

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply. Glad to see you've already solved the issue. You can indeed use the product id to get the barcode for products. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with this plugins; however, from your screenshot it looks like `_ywbc_barcode_image` does not have a value.

It might be considered slightly hacky, but why not build the filename yourself? Example:

```
$barcodeFile = sprintf( "Image%s_QRcode_%s.png", array(
    get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ywbc_barcode_value', true ),
    get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ywbc_barcode_value', true ) ) );
```

That'll give you a value of `Image5582_QRcode_5582.png`. Which you can use to insert where needed; such-as inside an image tag.

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/yith-barcodes/<?php echo $barcodeFile; ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the code you mention says the following: Syntax error unexpected T_STRING, expecting ´)´ `<?php $barcodeFile = sprintf( "Image%s_QRcode_%s.png", array(
    get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ywbc_barcode_value', true ),
    get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ywbc_barcode_value', true ) ); ?>
    
    <img src="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-content/uploads/yith-barcodes/<?php echo $barcodeFile ?>">`

Comment: @Williams Sorry about that. I've updated my answer to include the missing ')'.

Comment: now it display an invalid image and the url of that image is: **https://www.mi-domain/wp-content/uploads/yith-barcodes/** apparently you are not loading the full address of the image to display it.

Comment: You'll have to locate the images on your system and may have to adjust the IMG tag to your specific need. It's not a fix all solution.

Comment: The images I can locate them permanently in: mi-domain/wp-content/uploads/yith-barcodes/Image5582_QRcode_5582.png I can visualize them like this directly without problems.

Comment: apparently your code doesn't work, I deleted it, and sample the same, it has no effect. `<img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/yith-barcodes/<?php echo $barcodeFile; ?>">` and this is the one that doesn't work: `<?php $barcodeFile = sprintf( "Image%s_QRcode_%s.png", array(
    get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ywbc_barcode_value', true ),
    get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ywbc_barcode_value', true ) ) ); ?>`

Comment: If I use this code it only shows me the barcode of each product but not the image `<?php
    echo get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ywbc_barcode_value', true );
    ?>`